# MongoDB: Sending Profiling information to a file

Tags: mongodb

I've looked over the documentation, and I can't find anything about writing the results of system profiling to a log file. Was this a feature in older version of MongoDB?

http://techblog.holidaycheck.com/profiling-mongodb-with-logstash-and-kibana/

The author of this post mentions that setting the profiling level to 1 would result in MongoDB writing both to a system.profile collection and to the log files. I see the system.profile collection, but nothing in the log files. I've tried setting the profiling level to 2. Still no luck.

If I want to create visualizations from the data using Kibana, would I be better off exporting the system.profile collection or setting up Packetbeat (https://www.elastic.co/blog/mongodb-monitoring-with-packetbeat-and-elasticsearch)?

Comment: Yes you would be better off using the `system.profile` collection. This is often a point of confusion. If you are really set on slicing and dicing log files rather than working with an easy to use collection that queries just like any other collection, then since MongoDB 3.x there has been [`.setLogLevel()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.setLogLevel/). Turning up the verbosity of various components creates more noise in the server log.